# Validating Months / Years with jquery validate

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I am trying to link two form fields using jQuery validate. 
The user can only enter up to 5 years, but this is spread over two inputs, months and years.

I have worked out to the following how I feel it should come together :

```
$('#leform')validate({
debug: true,
rules: {
    years : {
        required : {
            depends: function(element) {
                  var x = ($('#years').val() == 5) && ($('#months').val() == 0),
                      y = ($('#years').val() < 5),
                      z = (x || y);
                       return z;

                },
        number : true,
        max : 5,
        min : 0

        },
        months : {
            required : true,
            number : true,
            min: 0,  
            max: 11 
        }
 }
});
```

The user can input, 3 years 6 months, no problem, but the issue lies when the user inputs 5 years, 4 months I cannot get the validation to fire.  Any ideas?

-------- EDIT / SOLUTION ---------

Sorry im a pretty new user (long time lurker) so had to edit the question to post the answer

Ok so it turns out I was misinterpreting the spec, it looks like "required" is a boolean true or false.

I extended the validation with the following :

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("yearCount", function(value, element) {
   var x = ($('#years').val() == 5) && ($('#months').val() == 0),
   y = ($('#years').val() < 5),
   z = (x || y);
   return z;
}, "blah blah blah");
```

and updated the rules as follows :

```
required : true,
max : 5,
min : 0,
yearCount : true
```

Comment: Does copying the "depends" function inside the months section help?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the following function for the `depends:` property for *both* controls:

```
function (){
    return $('#years').val() * 12 + $('#months').val() * 1 <= 60;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
$('#leform').validate({
  debug: true,
  rules: {
    years : {
      required : {
        depends: function(element) {
          return (($(element).val() == 5 && $('#months').val() == 0) || ($(element).val() < 5));
        },
        number : true,
        max : 5,
        min : 0

      },
      months : {
        required : true,
        number : true,
        min: 0,  
        max: 11 
      }
    }
  }
});
```